# How to get values in list at incremental indexes in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm looking at getting values in a list with an increment.

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

and I want something like:

```
[0,4,6,7]
```

At the moment I am using `l[0::2]`  but I would like sampling to be sparse at the beginning and increase towards the end of the list.

The reason I want this is because the list represents the points along a line from the center of a circle to a point on its circumference. At the moment I iterate every 10 points along the lines and draw a circle with a small radius on each. Therefore, my circles close to the center tend to overlap and I have gaps as I get close to the circle edge. I hope this provides a bit of context.

Thank you !

Comment: Would you please clarify you requirements?

Comment: Do you mean decrease at the end?

Comment: Just split it into two tasks. 1.) Build your desired list of indices or use a generator function. 2.) Iterate over the indices list/iterable. "sparse at the beginning" and "increase towards the end" are vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be more complicated than it sounds... You need a list of indices starting at zero and ending at the final element position in your list, presumably with no duplication (i.e. you don't want to get the same points twice). A generic way to do this would be to define the number of points you want first and then use a generator (`scaled_series`) that produces the required number of indices based on a function. We need a second generator (`unique_ints`) to ensure we get integer indices and no duplication.

```
def scaled_series(length, end, func):
    """ Generate a scaled series based on y = func(i), for an increasing 
    function func, starting at 0, of the specified length, and ending at end
    """

    scale = float(end) / (func(float(length)) - func(1.0))
    intercept = -scale * func(1.0)
    print 'scale', scale, 'intercept', intercept
    for i in range(1, length + 1):
        yield scale * func(float(i)) + intercept

def unique_ints(iter):
    last_n = None
    for n in iter:
        if last_n is None or round(n) != round(last_n):
            yield int(round(n))
            last_n = n

L = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
print [L[i] for i in unique_ints(scaled_series(4, 7, lambda x: 1 - 1 / (2 * x)))]
```

In this case, the function is 1 - 1/2x, which gives the series you want [0, 4, 6, 7]. You can play with the length (4) and the function to get the kind of spacing between the circles you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exact algorithm you want to use, but if it is non-constant, as your example appears to be, then you should consider creating a generator function to yield values:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

Depending on what your desire here is, you may want to consider a built in interpolator like scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d

Basically, given your question, you can't do it with the basic slice operator. Without more information this is the best answer I can give you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#slice) function to create a range of indices. You can then extend your sliced list with other slices.

```
k = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
r = slice(0,len(k)//2,4)
t = slice(r.stop,None,1)
j = k[r]
j.extend(k[t])
print(j) #outputs: [0,4,5,6,7]
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is just use list comprehension to retrieve the values. It is not possible to do it just by indexing. This is what I came up with:

```
l = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
m = [l[0]] + [l[1+sum(range(3, s-1, -1))] for s in [x for x in range(3, 0, -1)]]
```

and here is a breakdown of the code into loops:

```
# Start the list with the first value of l (the loop does not include it)
m = [l[0]]
# Descend from 3 to 1 ([3, 2, 1])
for s in range(3, 0, -1):
    # append 1 + sum of [3], [3, 2] and [3, 2, 1]
    m.append(l[ 1 + sum(range(3, s-1, -1)) ])
```

Both will give you the same answer:

```
>>> m
[0, 4, 6, 7]
```

I made this graphic that would I hope will help you to understand the process:
[image: explanation of cumulative sum]